# With ansible, how do I read a file and use the IP address contained as an argument to update an Azure MySQL firewall?

Tags: azure, ansible

My current project is to create a DigitalOcean Droplet and add the IP address to the Azure MySQL server firewall. In my script to spin up the Droplet I save the IP address as a .txt with only the IPv4 address. The ansible playbook I have now uses the following to read from the file and store the IP address as a variable.

```
vars:
  droplet_ip: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/created-droplet-ip.txt') }}"
```

I print this out in my playbook for debugging and it's the correct IP in the correct format (x.x.x.x).

I'm using `azure_rm_mysqlfirewallrule` to create the rule for this new address. I can login to Azure, find the resource group and server name but I get an error when using my `droplet_ip` variable, which is:

```
File \"/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py\", line 674, in validate\n    raise ValidationError(key, name, value)\nmsrest.exceptions.ValidationError: Parameter 'FirewallRule.start_ip_address' must conform to the following pattern: '^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$'.\n"
```

When I type the IP address out as the parameter it works fine so I'm 99% certain it's either how I'm reading the file or using the variable name. For this to be automated that isn't a possibility for me so if anyone can help I would be extremely grateful.

Below is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: local
  vars:
    droplet_ip: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/created-droplet-ip.txt') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Print droplet_ip
      debug:
        msg: "{{ droplet_ip }}"

    - name: Azure login
      shell: az login

    - name: Update firewall
      azure_rm_mysqlfirewallrule:
        ad_user: x@y.com
        resource_group: example_group
        server_name: example-dbs
        name: new_machine
        password: ******
        start_ip_address: droplet_ip
        end_ip_address: droplet_ip
        subscription_id: xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
        tenant: yyyyyyyy-yyyyyyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Comment: In order to figure out what's going on, we need to see your playbook, or at least a minimal example that reproduces the problem when you run it.

Comment: Good shout, just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include the value of the `droplet_ip` variable in your task, you need to write:

```
        start_ip_address: "{{ droplet_ip }}"
```

The way it's written write now, you're trying to set `start_ip_address` (et al) to the literal string "droplet_ip".